# Sass @use not working with separated mixin files into master mixin file (ERR: Undefined Mixin)

Tags: sass, scss-mixins, prepros

I'm a bit newer to sass, but when I was learning it the Sass website said to start using @use instead of import, so after a lot of trial and error I finally figured out how to use it pretty much the same as import.

**Note: I'm using Prepros for compiling.**

I have this mixin in it's own file inside of a `mixins` folder:

```
// scss/mixins/_flex.scss

@mixin flex($flex-flow: row, $justify-content: center, $align-items: center) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: $justify-content;
    align-items: $align-items;
    flex-flow: $flex-flow;
}
```

I tried `@use`ing it in my main `_mixins.scss` file:

```
// scss/_mixins.scss

@use "mixins/flex" as *;
```

Then I tried using it in another one of my files containing common elements:

```
// scss/_common_elements.scss

@use "mixins" as *;

.flex {
  @include flex();
}
```

Then I receive the error inside of Prepros log: `Undefined Mixin` where I call the `@include flex();` line (inside of _common_elements.scss)

It was working until I decided to put the mixins in their own separate folder, but this is the same as how it's setup inside of Bootstraps source code.

This whole process of using `@use` has been really confusing.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it!

ALSO: If you can help me edit this question / answer to better explain it with proper language, please post suggestions and I'll update it.

In the `_mixins.scss` file I needed to use `@forward "mixins/flex"` instead of `@use "mixins/flex" as *;`:

Like this:

```
// scss/_mixins.scss 

@forward "mixins/flex";
@forward "mixins/overlay";
@forward "mixins/etc...";
```

I wish they would've made this something more clear on the actual [sass @use documentation.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)

Here are the [actual docs to @forward.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward)

Answer (score 0):

to use `@use` command and other new features of sass, you need to install dart sass, and not node-sass;

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass